# Multiple API calls using rest template

Tags: rest, spring-boot, resttemplate

I have a Microservice developed in spring boot 1.5.4 . It exposes a number of restful GET and POST methods .A particular "GET" method , in turn calls 2 other Micorservices using Spring rest template to construct the  response.

The problem here is when under load, the response time of the "GET" method keeps on increasing, even though the other 2 microservices respond faster.
I see from the logs that, after the first call, the code doesn't execute the 2nd Api call, instead waits for some of the other threads to finish the first Api call, then executes the 2nd Api call.

This causes a great increase in response time, and causes a headache in production environment.
Can someone please explain the above behavior, and what can be done to improve the response time (by calling both the Apis in sequence instead of waiting)

This is my rest template bean config.
I just Autowire this rest template and call the other 2 microservices.

```
@Autowired
MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter;

@Value("${rest.template.readTimeout:10000}")
private int readTimeout;
@Value("${rest.template.connectionTimeout:10000}")
private int connectionTimeout;

@Bean
public ClientHttpRequestFactory getClientHttpRequestFactory() {

    HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory factory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
    factory.setReadTimeout(readTimeout);
    factory.setConnectTimeout(connectionTimeout);
    return new BufferingClientHttpRequestFactory(factory);
}

@Bean
public RestTemplate getRestTemplate(ClientHttpRequestFactory factory) {

    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(factory);

    List<ClientHttpRequestInterceptor> interceptors = new ArrayList<>();

    interceptors.add(new ClientLoggingtInterceptor());

    restTemplate.setInterceptors(interceptors);

    List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverters = new ArrayList<HttpMessageConverter<?>>();
    messageConverters.add(new FormHttpMessageConverter());
    messageConverters.add(new StringHttpMessageConverter());
    messageConverters.add(mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter);

    restTemplate.setMessageConverters(messageConverters);
    restTemplate.setErrorHandler(getCustomErrorHandler());

    return restTemplate;
}

@Bean
public CustomErrorHandler getCustomErrorHandler() {
    return new CustomErrorHandler();
}
```

Comment: When you say after the first call, you mean after the response of the call is received?

Comment: Yes, that's correct

Comment: I had to mention, that in the same Microservice , another "GET" method, which in turn calls another Microservice using rest template works great under load.

Comment: maybe providing some code can help

Comment: Added some code above

Comment: So this same `RestTemplate` is used for all requests and for some performs bad and for others good?

Comment: I would not say some perform bad, I would say when there is more than one Api call involved (like calling 2 other micorservices) it performs bad

Comment: Difficult to guess, it would require some log inspection to have a better idea of what is happenig

Comment: The problem occurs only under load test (did with 50 threads)

Comment: Is there any specific log I should check ? any lead can be helpful.

Comment: And btw is the following possible?when a request is in process (like calling the first Microservice ) , the request that comes after that are given preference to access the rest template/connections (to call the first Microservice)?
Since the 2nd Microservice call will be invoked only when the first is complete, which results in the first request waiting.

Comment: I would suggest 2 things: 1) Try to replicate the issue on a consistent basis; 2) Once you are able to replicate the issue check (application) logs to see if you can see something strange. Also, try to include some code snippet of the API in question.